# Exception when creating on demand loactor for Azure Media Services asset

Tags: c#, azure, azure-media-services

I'm using Azure Functions for accessing Azure Media Services. I have a HTTP trigger that will get me a streaming link for a video file. 
When I try to create an on demand streaming locator the server sometimes return the following error:

> One or more errors occurred. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client: An error occurred while processing this request.
>   **Locator's ExpirationDateTime cannot be in the past**.

Here is part of the code:

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client;
...
public static readonly TimeSpan ExpirationTimeThreshold = TimeSpan.FromHours(5);
public static readonly DateTime TimeSkew = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5);
...

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    string assetId = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs().FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "assetId", true) == 0).Value;

    IAsset wantedAsset = _context.Assets.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(assetId)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (wantedAsset == null)
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
        "No asset matches the Id");

    }

    originLocator = wantedAsset.Locators.Where(l => l.Type == LocatorType.OnDemandOrigin).FirstOrDefault();

    if (originLocator == null)
    {
        IAccessPolicy policy = _context.AccessPolicies.Create("Streaming policy",
        ExpirationTimeThreshold,
        AccessPermissions.Read);

        originLocator = _context.Locators.CreateLocator(LocatorType.OnDemandOrigin, wantedAsset,
        policy, 
        TimeSkew); //This is where the exception is returned
    }
    ...
}
```

This seems to be very inconsistent behaviour, as it will work as expected most of the time. 
Once when this happened I tried to put in log statements in the Azure Function, and when I saved the changes the function worked as expected.

One thing I realized as I was writing this is that the `TimeSkew` variable will not be updated until I save the changes to the Azure Functions.
This means that the first time this is run the `TimeSkew` would for example be 5:00PM and after 5 hours the `TimeSkew` would still be 5:00PM, meaning the `ExpirationTimeThreshold` and the `TimeSkew` will negate each other?

Making `TimeSkew` a local variable should then fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already answered your own question. Every time you recompile (or more specifically, every time a new instance starts running your function), the `TimeSkew` static variable is initialized. For all subsequent requests to the same instance, `TimeSkew` value stays the same, which probably leads to the mentioned error.

Solution: don't initialize any static variable to `DateTime.Now` related things, unless you really want to track the start time of the first run on each instance (which you don't).

Comment: Seems that way, just tested it and it should work fine now